# JQuery Memory Cache in IE

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, internet-explorer

I got a problem with JQuery in IE. The code works perfectly in firefox. I have a small form which add two details to db through ajax. This is my code

```
$("#add").click(function(){
            $("#all_villa tr").remove();                                     
            var villa_name = $("#villa_name").val();
            var villa_desp = $("#villa_desp").val();
            var dataString = "villa_name=" + villa_name + "&villa_desp=" + villa_desp;
            $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "ajax_snippets/add_villa.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function(data) { 
                    $("#all_villa tr").remove();
                    $("#msg").html(data);
                    $("#villa_name").val('');
                    $("#villa_desp").val('');
                    $("#all_villa").load("ajax_snippets/all_villa.php");
                }
            });             
            return false;
        });
```

After the details saved to db, a new line will be added to the table below to the form which contains the added details and two datepicker fields and two links to update and delete. When I test with IE, after the details added to the db, the lines will not be created and the existing update and delete links also not working. following are my update and delete codes

```
$("#all_villa .delete").click(function(){
        var k = this.id;
        var i = k.substr(3,4);
        var dataString = "id="+i;
        if(confirm("Do you really want to delete this villa?")){
            $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "ajax_snippets/delete_villa.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function(data) { 
                    $("#villa"+i).remove();
                    $("#msg").html(data);
                }
            }); 
        }else{}
            return false;
    });

    $("#all_villa .update").click(function(){
        var i = this.id;
        var from = $("#from_date"+i).val();
        var to = $("#to_date"+i).val();
        var available = $("#available"+i).val();
        if(from == ""){
            alert("From Date is Required"); 
            return false;
        }
        if(to == ""){
            alert("To Date is Required");   
            return false;
        }
        if(available == ""){
            alert("Availability is Required");
            return false;
        }
        var dataString = "from="+from+"&to="+to+"&id="+i+"&avlbl="+available;
            $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "ajax_snippets/update_villa.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function(data) { 
                    $("#msg").html(data);
                    $("#villa_name").val('');
                    $("#villa_desp").val('');
                    $("#all_villa").load("ajax_snippets/all_villa.php");
                }
            });             
            return false;
    });
```

Can anybody tell me where did I made the wrong turn

Thanks

Comment: your else in .delete click is pointless :) , just so you know, not being rude

Comment: `.click` should be with `.live` as its a dynamic element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the following line and it works fine, hope this will help someone

```
$("#villa_tbl").load("ajaxsnippets/all_villa.php",{noncache: new Date().getTime()},function(){});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `cache: false,` to your ajax parameters

Comment: Added it, but no luck, same result

Comment: I think there's a problem in my code, then I have try the jquery.live, thanks

Comment: Hmmm, are you using Firebug in Firefox, is there an error when you click?